# Redirect from Controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect

In my controller BVZ\Customer\Controller\Index I'm doing a redirect using

```
return $this->_redirect('customer/index/firstAccess');
```

When the code execute, the request are made (see the print below)
below 
[image]

but the url in browser stay in the same place.

how can i make the page redirect to 'customer/index/firstAccess' and not just make the request?

all code of my controller

```
<?php

namespace BVZ\Customer\Controller\Index;

class CustomerExists extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
  ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
  }

  public function execute() {
    $cpfcpnj = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cpfcpnj');

    $vowels = array("-", ".","/");
    $cpfcpnj = str_replace($vowels, "", $cpfcpnj);

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
    $collection = $customerObj
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('taxvat',$cpfcpnj)
                  ->load()
                  ->getFirstItem();

  if($collection->getId()) {

      if($collection->getData('firstAccess')!=0){

          //email reset
          return $this->_redirect('customer/account/ResetPasswordPost');
          $return = "first";
      } else {
          $return = "exists";
      }

  } else {
      $return = "new";
  }

  $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
  return $result->setData($return);
```

Comment: Hi, Please provide more information about your code and files to make it easier for everyone to understand the problem better.

Comment: Hello, i have updated the question. Please check if became clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('routername/controllerpath/controllername');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

Comment: This way it worked.

I just needed to improve the AJAX, how the request was made via AJAX, the process redirect worked in php, but JS continued the process without counting this redirect. So I needed to set where I want to go in php and use another call in JS to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

### Controller Result

Review this file: `vendor/magento/framework/Controller/ResultFactory.php`

Here is a sample of the `ResultFactory` usage:

```
// The use statement below is for constants. $this->resultFactory is inherited from parent class
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Sample extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);

    $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);   

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');

}
```